# Fill DataGridView with stored procedure (that has joins) through WCF service c#

Tags: c#, wcf, stored-procedures, data-binding, datagridview

I'm calling WCF Service that gives me a list of customers with specified field values in the BAL.

When I initialize it to display data in `DataGridView` everything that has the corresponding data type values from `Customer` table is showing up (such as `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Phone1`).

However the values that I want to retrieve from `Country` table using `inner join` in the stored procedure do not want to display the corresponding values in the `Customer` table.

And error is that the `CountryId` is `DBNull` in `Customer` table, how do I solve it for this particular example.

Here is my code for binding data (which is working for certain fields):

```
IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
List<CustomerListItem> customerlist = res.GetCustomerListItem();
_ListData = ToDataTable(customerlist);
```

This is my method in BAL:

```
public List<CustomerListItem> GetCustomerListItem()
{
    List<CustomerListItem> customerlist = null;
    CustomerListItem item = null;
    using (CustomerTableAdapter adp = new CustomerTableAdapter())
    {
        using (DAL.dstCustomer.CustomerDataTable tbl = adp.GetCustomerDataList())
        {
            customerlist = new List<CustomerListItem>();
            foreach (var row in tbl)
            {
                item = new CustomerListItem();
                item.FirstName = row.FirstName;
                item.LastName = row.LastName;
                item.Phone1 = row.Phone1;
                string mystring = row.CountryId.ToString(); //i tried to convert it to string but it still gives me the error that 'The value for column 'CountryId' in table 'Customer' is DBNull.'
                item.CountryId = mystring;
                //item.NationalityId = row.NationalityId;
                customerlist.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return customerlist;
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CustomerDataList] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT cu.FirstName, cu.LastName, cu.Phone1, co.CountryName, n.Nationality 
FROM Customer cu
Left Join Country co
ON cu.CountryId = co.CountryId
Left Join Nationality n
ON cu.NationalityId = n.NationalityId
WHERE cu.IsDeleted = 0
END
```

[image: Executing stored procedure]
[image: dstCustomer]

If any more code samples are required please let me know.

Comment: which line has the error?

Comment: the error is coming from the BAL where `CountryId` is dbnull in the customer table

Comment: @UZIERSKI - so in the underlying table, are there actually null values anywhere in the country ID field?

Comment: @UZIERSKI - Also, if you run the sql statements within the stored procedure you mention does it return nulls in the customer ID field? I strongly suspect there is either an issue in your query or within the binding in your DAL that is producing the null values you are not expecting.

Comment: @HBomb there are not any null values in the CountryId when I execute the query. All of them correspond to values in Country table and are displayed. I will add some screenshots as a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CountryId to the Stored Procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CustomerDataList] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT cu.FirstName, cu.LastName, cu.Phone1, co.CountryId, co.CountryName, n.Nationality 
FROM Customer cu
Left Join Country co
ON cu.CountryId = co.CountryId
Left Join Nationality n
ON cu.NationalityId = n.NationalityId
WHERE cu.IsDeleted = 0
END
```

Then add CountryName to the model:

```
public class CustomerListItem
{
    string CountryName = string.Empty;
...
}
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem the error is still appearing.

Comment: Do a **Coalesce(CountryId,0)** in the stored procedure instead

Comment: It gives sqlexception error in `using (DAL.dstCustomer.CustomerDataTable tbl = adp.GetCustomerDataList())` - Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Benin' to data type int.

Comment: the problem also appears in the procedure when I try to execute it.

Comment: Ok, edit your question to include the sproc, it sounds like you are using Country instead of CountryId or a simple mistake like that, double check

Comment: I Included stored procedure in the question and included outcome of that procedure. When I select I select column names from three tables, but I reference their ID's. I suspected that this could be the issue but how do I specify those columns in the code. I though the procedure would do that for me.

Comment: When I use `CountryId` instead of `CountryName` the result is displayed but as I number I want t display the country name itself (not the corresponding ID) on the user interface on the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Thanks, the error disappeared but the data for the country column is not showing anything within the data grid view.

Comment: Hi, any luck recently, my gut feeling is to double check the bindings. I know you've probably done this 100 times, maybe posting screenshots of that will lead to that 'aha' moment

Answer (score 0):

This was too ugly to put in comments. Here goes:

So you added your Country name into your dataModel as so:

```
public class CustomerListItem
{
    string CountryName = string.Empty;
...
}
```

Thats good, but we aren't quite finished. We now have to *actually populate* the new property, with an additional line of code (emphasis added in comments).

```
public List<CustomerListItem> GetCustomerListItem()
{
    List<CustomerListItem> customerlist = null;
    CustomerListItem item = null;
    using (CustomerTableAdapter adp = new CustomerTableAdapter())
    {
        using (DAL.dstCustomer.CustomerDataTable tbl = adp.GetCustomerDataList())
        {
            customerlist = new List<CustomerListItem>();
            foreach (var row in tbl)
            {
                item = new CustomerListItem();
                item.FirstName = row.FirstName;
                item.LastName = row.LastName;
                item.Phone1 = row.Phone1;
                string mystring = row.CountryId.ToString(); //i tried to convert it to string but it still gives me the error that 'The value for column 'CountryId' in table 'Customer' is DBNull.'
                item.CountryId = mystring;
                //item.NationalityId = row.NationalityId;

                //Here's the new line, where we actually populate our new model property
                item.CountryName  = row.CountryName;
                customerlist.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return customerlist;
}
```

You now have to update your TableAdapter to include the new values being returned from the sproc.

The easiest way is to go into the Designer (where you grabbed the screenshot from) right click on the top portion of the grid, and then click configure. You should be able to walk though the wizard from there to get the designer to update the DataTable and include the new field. When successful you should see the new field in the top portion of the grid (you may have to manually edit the select statement within the wizard to include it, it just depends on how it was initially setup).

Again, depending on the initial setup, you may also have to right click on your GetCustomerDataList() in the bottom portion of the designer and click configure to walk through that additional wizard as well to get that method to include the new field from the sproc. There is no harm in doing this step even if not necessary, so I'd recommend it in your case.

Here are a few MSDN reference points for working with TableAdapters and DataSets in general.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/04y282hb(v=VS.140).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171902(v=vs.140).aspx

Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Yeah still having issues seems like the `CountryName` row is not within the `dstCustomer` although I updated it.

Comment: I added how my `dstCustomer` looks like.

Comment: Updated answer with additional details on why this is occurring and how to fix it by updating your TableAdapter and DataSet in the Visual Designer.